# Launching Python code on start-up

Tags: raspbian, python, cron, python-2.x

I'm making a robot using a Raspberry Pi.

I have written code for it in Python and I would like the Python script to run as soon as the Pi is powered.

I only want the whole script to repeat the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

First in `raspi-config` select `Boot Options` then `Desktop/CLI` then `Console Autologin`.

Then in a Terminal window run:

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

At the bottom add:

```
sudo python /home/pi/yourscript.py
```

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then press <kbd>Y</kbd> followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> twice.

`/home/pi/` is the directory of your python file and `yourscript.py` is the name of your python code.

To check this works reboot the Pi. If you want the Python code to repeat, in your Python code set up some kind of While loop and that would work. Alternatively you could look into using [Cron](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md). However, depending on how you coded you program it might run indefinitely anyway.

Comment: What's the point in the console autologin?

Comment: The auto-login is optional. It essentially means the Pi is able to start the Python script running without a user having to log in. This might be useful if you can't SSH into the Pi or connect a monitor to the Pi, the Pi can just be switched on and the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Cron Job:

```
( sudo crontab -l; echo "@reboot" $(which python) /home/pi/foo ) | sudo crontab -
```

If your sketch doesn't need to be run as root, you can omit both `sudo` parts and run it as your current user, at boot.

Just replace `/home/pi/foo` with the full path to your python sketch.  The `@reboot` will run the path to your sketch in your current version of Python, upon a complete reboot.